# IS ILLEGAL WORKING HARAM?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, work, banking

I wanna ask, I currently left a job at bank, (due to it being riba based) and recently I got hired in a Real Estate company, after I joined, I came to learn that my job role i.e. Telecalling for Real Estate clients is apparently illegal in the region I work in, there are hefty fines if cold call recipient complaints to govt, however, for the most part, people do not complain, (even if they do, the company is fined, not the agent, and the company is ok with that risk) pretty much all real estate companies are doing this cold calling - which allows them to connect to potential sellers and connect them to buyers. Some people however, do not like us calling them, get bothered, however, if someone does show annoyance, we don't call them and keep their contact highlighted to not contact them. Would doing this job be haram? (Alternatively, until I found this job, I was providing car pool services to people since cab is very expensive and making money like that) which is also illegal as per law. I am studying at the moment and hope to get a good job once my studies are completed, but still I want my earnings to be halal, but this is my situation. Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
Allahﷻ bless you.
*your work is permissible/Halal*
Country law is just a law established by a group of people, so this does not make your work forbidden،